# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText.getText()'

Tags: nullpointerexception, gettext

please help me

Pressing the register button does not return a toast message, the app stops, and the following code:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText.getText()' on a null object reference

I also used String.ofValue instead of toString.

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MaterialEditText username, email, password;
    Button btn_register;

    FirebaseAuth auth;
    DatabaseReference reference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Register");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        username = findViewById(R.id.username);
        email = findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = findViewById(R.id.password);
        btn_register = findViewById(R.id.btn_register);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        btn_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String txt_username = username.getText().toString();
                String txt_email = email.getText().toString();
                String txt_password = password.getText().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(txt_username) || TextUtils.isEmpty(txt_email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(txt_password)){
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "All fields are required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (txt_password.length() < 6){
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "password must be at least 6 character", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    register(txt_username, txt_email, txt_password);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void register(final String username, String email, String password) {

        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            FirebaseUser firebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
                            assert firebaseUser != null;
                            String userid = firebaseUser.getUid();

                            reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users" ).child(userid);

                            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                            hashMap.put("id", userid);
                            hashMap.put("username", username);
                            hashMap.put("imageURL", "default");

                            reference.setValue(hashMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public  void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "You can't register with this email or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Copy my codes and compare your codes with mine
```

**Java Code**

Look carefully at the Java code

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MaterialEditText username, email, password;
    Button btn_register;

    FirebaseAuth auth;
    DatabaseReference reference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Register");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        username = findViewById(R.id.username);
        email = findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = findViewById(R.id.password);
        btn_register = findViewById(R.id.btn_register);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        btn_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String txt_username = username.getText().toString();
                String txt_email = email.getText().toString();
                String txt_password = password.getText().toString();
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(txt_username) || TextUtils.isEmpty(txt_email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(txt_password)){
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "All fileds are required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else if (txt_password.length() < 6){
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "password must be at least 6 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    register(txt_username, txt_email, txt_password);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void register(String username, String email, String password){

        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            FirebaseUser firebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
                            assert firebaseUser != null;
                            String userid = firebaseUser.getUid();

                            reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userid);

                            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                            hashMap.put("id", userid);
                            hashMap.put("username", username);
                            hashMap.put("imageURL", "default");

                            reference.setValue(hashMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "You can't register woth this email or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

**XML Code**

Look carefully at the xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RegisterActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/bar_layout"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Create a new account"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>


        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:met_floatingLabel="normal"
            android:hint="Username"/>

        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:met_floatingLabel="normal"
            android:hint="Email"/>

        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:met_floatingLabel="normal"
            android:hint="Password"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="register"
            android:id="@+id/btn_register"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```